# Spreading water-based Varathane that is 3 times thicker

Tags: finishing, polyurethane

I used water-based 3X Varathane on a table top I am refinishing.  It is very difficult to spread because it is so thick.  It is supposed to be "self-leveling".  I cannot brush it on evenly because it is so thick and it starts to dry (and gum up when I go back to even it out).  Some areas are much thicker than others.

I have sanded it lightly but an hoping for some guidance before I try a second coat!

Comment: If someone doesn't come along who has experience with this product specifically and can pass on some tips your best bet would be to contact the maker. Finish manufacturers can be quite good at getting back to consumers who email in a query and they often (though not always!) know their products best and can offer the best advice.

Comment: Now I don't use this (wrong part of the world) but I can suggest a few things you could try. The first is applying it with a short-nap or foam roller instead of a brush. I *hate* applying waterbased anything only by brush and have found that 9/10 a roller works way better, either by itself or used to quickly even out the finish after slapping it on quickly by brush. 2nd, try thinning a tad. You're not supposed to thin waterbased finishes but diluting just a little won't do any harm and may reduce the viscosity just enough to make the Varathane workable enough that you can deal with it.